# How do you put the div to the right

Tags: css, tailwind-css

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/0.7.4/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<header class="bg-red p-5 flex border-b-2 border-white border-b-4">
  <h1 class="font-display text-white text-md tracking-tight font-medium uppercase">local app</h1>

  <div id="profile">
    <img class="h-16 w-16 rounded-full mb-2 border-white border-4" src="{{ asset('assets/images/avatar.jpg') }}" alt="">
  </div>
</header>
```

[image: Screenshot]

I want to put that avatar on the right beside “APP” on the farthest right, but I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: Can you edit the snippet to add a public link for the avatar images?

Comment: wdym ? sir ? i dk

Comment: I’ve added a runnable code snippet to your post so we can see how your code creates the output you’ve shown. But since your images aren’t accessible on the internet, they don’t show up. Can you please provide an actual URL for them (perhaps by adding them to the post then using the link generated in your code)

Comment: Please don't use text-speak in your comments.  Use full english words.  You can't expect people to know what "wdym" means....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use absolute position on the image container and set `right` to `1rem` or similar. The `right` attribute controls how far from the right the element should be placed. (But there are many other ways to do this)

```css
header {
  position: relative;
}

#profile {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/0.7.4/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<header class="bg-red p-5 flex border-b-2 border-white border-b-4">
  <h1 class="font-display text-white text-md tracking-tight font-medium uppercase">local app</h1>

  <div id="profile">
    <img class="h-16 w-16 rounded-full mb-2 border-white border-4" src="{{ asset('assets/images/avatar.jpg') }}" alt="">
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `margin-left:auto; margin-right:0;` on `<div id="profile">`

```css
#profile{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/0.7.4/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<header class="bg-red p-5 flex border-b-2 border-white border-b-4">
  <h1 class="font-display text-white text-md tracking-tight font-medium uppercase">local app</h1>

  <div id="profile">
    <img class="h-16 w-16 rounded-full mb-2 border-white border-4" src="{{ asset('assets/images/avatar.jpg') }}" alt="">
  </div>
</header>
```